# корректно ли в тег html добавить и класс и стиль

Tags: html

```xml
<p style="visibility:hidden" class="someStyle">blablabla</p>
<!--это по синтаксису написания-->
```

```xml
<p style="visibility:@visibleProperty" class="someStyle">blablabla</p>
<!--ну а это, чтоб понятней логика была, эту переменную я определяю в зависимости от необходимости-->
```

корректно ли в `html тег` добавить и стиль и класс ?

я добавила, работает, но не могу найти примера можно ли так использовать теги

Comment: уместно, если вы не намерены в будущем эти стили менять через css. Просто если нужно будет менять, тогда придётся использовать !important, что уже не правильно. Но с помощью JS можно будет переписать.

Comment: `@visibleProperty` — это не может работать, такого синтаксиса в css не существует

Comment: @andreymal скорее всего это просто пример показывающий что подставляется значение переменной. Как именно подставляется - не имеет значения

Comment: @Grundy для такого можно было бы написать `someValue` или `blablabla` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal, тогда было бы непонятно ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Технически все будет работать но стили нужно писать в отдельном файле все таки есть принцип seperation of concerns. Если в inline стилях есть свойство X и такое же свойство прописано под классом возникает конфликт и вступает правила приоритетности.